# new ClassName() {...} - что это?

Tags: java

Во время изучения Android Studio столкнулся вот с такой конструкцией:

```
mCrowsCounterButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mInfoTextView.setText("Я насчитал " + ++mCount + " ворон");
    }
});
```

Дальше коллекций язык Java не учил(или просто вылетело из головы). Как называются эти фигурные скобки после "new View.OnClickListener()" ?

Comment: Посмотрите [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/355167/how-are-anonymous-inner-classes-used-in-java)

Comment: Именованный класс с определением функции.